How to define hypothesis strategies for custom dataclasses
I am currently using hypothesis for fuzzing my test but I then need to generate random dataclasses, and so to build strategies for each, like
# Base types
uint64 = st.integers(min_value=0, max_value=2**64 - 1)
uint256 = st.integers(min_value=0, max_value=2**256 - 1)

# Dataclasses types
account = st.fixed_dictionaries(
    {
        "nonce": uint64,
        "balance": uint256,
        "code": st.binary(),
    }
).map(lambda x: Account(**x))

Is there a way to avoid this explicit strategy definition? Somehow like with rust arbitrary, producing well-typed, structured values, from raw, byte buffers.

Populating a memory segment with random bytes wouldn't actually produce valid Python objects, and I don't think Rust's Arbitrary trait works that way either.

XY problem? If you want to generate instances of arbitrary dataclasses without creating explicit strategies, just ask for that; no need to introduce the red herring of “populating a memory segment with random bytes” unless you have a good reason.

Put all the instances in a list, and use random.choice() to select a random instance.

Raw memory allocation was indeed a misunderstanding and not relevant here sorry, I removed and rephrased the question, as you suggested @Ry-

I don’t want to generate manually a list of instances @Barmar, it goes against the purpose of fuzzing

I mean, you can of course do struct.unpack("<III", os.urandom(struct.calcsize("<III"))) to interpret some random data as integers.

@AKX for my personal knowledge, I don't understand how to run this code!

@ClementWalter Did you try it? import os, struct; struct.unpack("<III", os.urandom(struct.calcsize("<III"))) in the Python REPL and you'll get a 3-tuple of unsigned integers...

hypothesis.strategies.builds says

Dataclasses are handled natively by the inference from type hints.

So if your dataclasses are type-hinted properly with types that are registered (or themselves introspectable) such that from_type returns the strategy you want, it should be just
account = st.builds(Account)

And if you’re using these in normal Hypothesis tests, you don’t even need to specify that; let Hypothesis infer it.

works very well with st.register_type_strategy thx
